# Xamarin - get max timestamp from table using SQLite-net PCL

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to get max timestamp in table. I am using [SQLite-net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) but value always returns null.

I check that the db instance passing correctly and datebase is filled with data.

Here is my method:

```
public long? GetLastItemsTimeStamp()
{
    try
    {
        List<long?> TimeStamp = db.Query<long?>("SELECT max (TimeStamp) FROM Items ;" ) ;
        return  (TimeStamp.Count > 0) ? TimeStamp[0] : null ;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I didnt get any exception

Comment: from quickWatcher , it return null value and didnt enter catch block , is this correct way to execute query or not ?

Comment: no my database have two items only filled with data , when I look at watcher it give me strange message "Method `Query<long?>' not found in type `SQLite.SQLiteConnection'."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129423/discussion-between-mina-fawzy-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Comment: it return null value come to chat please

Comment: its ok , can you guide me how to make query with this library as I am new to xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out away to do this, hope this helps anyone that faces the same issue.

```
 public long? GetLastItemsTimeStamp()
 {
     var table = db.Table<Item>();
     long timestamp = table.Max(x => x.TimeStamp);
     return timestamp ;
 }
```